# app terminates when erasing the image in ios

Tags: ios

what i have done is getting image from gallery which should
 be erased while moving finger on image using touch.my image is erasing.but problem is app terminates when erasing the image .my code is like this

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.sizeSlider.hidden=NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.shareView];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.shareView.frame.size);
    [imgForeGround.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.shareView.frame.size.width,  
    self.shareView.frame.size.height)];

    // I add this
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeClear);

    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), sizeSlider.value);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeClear);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    imgForeGround.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    lastPoint = currentPoint;

    [imgForeGround setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

please anybody help me to avoid this memory leaks of this problem help is appreciated

Comment: Check out the scratchable views [here][1]




  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505095/erase-color-of-imageviews-background-color-with-touch-io

Comment: Actually i have one image only..but that link has two images right.i wnat

Comment: thats not works ..plz is there any way

Comment: You can check [this][1] answer.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607663/how-to-erase-image-by-using-touch-in-objective-c-ios

Hope it helps...

Comment: thankq for replying me..but my controls are not working what u have u posted links

Comment: if u don't mind please tell me solution in my code..is there any mistake i did

Answer (score 0):

There are few more controls easy to implement:

https://github.com/moqod/iOS-Scratch-n-See

Comment: my app does not crash in simulator..but its crashing in device only ..that link is not working with my controls please help me with any other solution

Comment: i have one doubt regarding image based color picker..when i click color picker button applying colors where we touch with finger on my erased image .upto nw is fine.but when i click done button this colorAppliedimage goes to first view ..

Comment: my problem is only image goes to that view not with background color ..i want to get color applied image ..please anyone halpme to do this

Comment: viewContrlr=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
  viewContrlr.inputImage=self.colorimgView.image;
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];